# Swift casting error where there shouldn't be

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to display one of two xib files depending on what is inside the array driving the UITable Population, however I am getting a casting error in the following function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if(phoneNo[indexPath.row] == "dropdowncell") {
            //this means that the cell populated should be a dropdown cell
            let nib2 = UINib(nibName: "DropDownOptionsCell", bundle: nil)
            print("dropdown if statement hit son")

            self.myTableView.register(nib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            let cell2 = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DropDownOptionsCell

            //cell2.dropDown.tag = indexPath.row
            //cell2.dropDown.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.test(sender:)), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

            return cell2
        }
        else {
            //this means the cell populated should be a contact cell
            let nib = UINib(nibName: "ContactCell", bundle: nil)

            self.myTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ContactCell

            print("/n/n below is the cell")
            print(cell)

            //below gets the index
            var val = indexPath.row

            print("beliw is the name")
            print(name)

            print("/n/n below is the val")
            print(val)

            cell.dropDown.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.dropDown.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.test(sender:)), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

            if(phoneNo.contains("dropdowncell")) {
                //this gets rid of uneven amount in the two arrays
                var testArray = [String]()
                testArray = phoneNo
                print(phoneNo)
                print("drop down index below")
                print(dropDownIndex)
                let testInd = testArray.remove(at: dropDownIndex)
                print("below is the testArray")
                print(testArray)
                val = testArray.count
            }

            //below assigns the values of the fields on the cell
            //cell.contactName.text = (name[val])

            return cell
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

This function is failing due to the following error:

> Could not cast value of type 'Phlare.ContactCell' (0x1056a1fe8) to 'Phlare.DropDownOptionsCell'

This error is occurring on the following line of code:

```
let cell2 = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DropDownOptionsCell
```

Comment: Do not use same identifier for both cells. Also, Why do you `register()` inside `cellForRowAt()`?

Comment: Is `Phlare.ContactCell` a subclass of `Phlare.DropDownOptionsCell`?

Comment: @mag_zbc no, they are both the swift files for the xib's I am attempting to load in the tableview

Comment: @Larme I was under the impression that if they are store in two separate variables it wouldn't matter.  Also, I just wanted to keep it clear which nib was being used where.  As long as you put it before the dequeue shouldn't there be no issue?

Comment: @Drew Register both nib on view didload() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have same cell identifier with both cells. Please carefully match the identifier on either of the cells before running .

Hope it helps.

I have just corrected your code by replacing the correct cell identifier.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if(phoneNo[indexPath.row] == "dropdowncell") {
            //this means that the cell populated should be a dropdown cell
            let nib2 = UINib(nibName: "DropDownOptionsCell", bundle: nil)
            print("dropdown if statement hit son")

            self.myTableView.register(nib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            let cell2 = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DropDownOptionsCell", for: indexPath) as! DropDownOptionsCell

            //cell2.dropDown.tag = indexPath.row
            //cell2.dropDown.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.test(sender:)), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

            return cell2
        }
        else {
            //this means the cell populated should be a contact cell
            let nib = UINib(nibName: "ContactCell", bundle: nil)

            self.myTableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactCell

            print("/n/n below is the cell")
            print(cell)

            //below gets the index
            var val = indexPath.row

            print("beliw is the name")
            print(name)

            print("/n/n below is the val")
            print(val)

            cell.dropDown.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.dropDown.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.test(sender:)), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

            if(phoneNo.contains("dropdowncell")) {
                //this gets rid of uneven amount in the two arrays
                var testArray = [String]()
                testArray = phoneNo
                print(phoneNo)
                print("drop down index below")
                print(dropDownIndex)
                let testInd = testArray.remove(at: dropDownIndex)
                print("below is the testArray")
                print(testArray)
                val = testArray.count
            }

            //below assigns the values of the fields on the cell
            //cell.contactName.text = (name[val])

            return cell
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```